# Showing a system of equations has no integer solutions using modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

Quite a trivial question in comparison to the ones found on here, but here it goes:

"By applying (mod 5) to both equations, show that the system of equations below has no integer solutions:

$11x^2 + 5xy = 7 $

$9x^2 + 10y^3 = −3$   "

Now, the solution jumps straight to:

$x^2 = 2 \pmod 5$

$-x^2 = -3 \pmod 5. $

I'm struggling to figure out how exactly they get to that stage, and at that, how these last two equations imply there are no integer solutions.

Comment: From equations you find out it follows immediately $0=-1$, absurde.

Comment: Without mod: adding the two equations yields $\,5(\cdots) = 4,\,$ i.e. $\,5\mid 4,\,$ contradiction

Answer (score 1):

$11x^2+5xy=7\implies x^2\equiv2\pmod5$, because $11\equiv1\pmod5, $

$5\equiv0\pmod5$, and $7\equiv2\pmod5$.

$9x^2+10y^3=-3\implies  -x^2\equiv-3\pmod5\iff x^2\equiv 3\pmod5$,

because $9\equiv-1\pmod5$ and $ 10\equiv0\pmod5$.

There are no solutions, because   $2\equiv x^2\equiv3\pmod5$ is a contradiction.